# App Switcher Randomly Pops Up 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, macbook, macbook-pro, magic-trackpad

I'm having the same issue described [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219542) on Ubuntu 16.04, running on a MacBook pro. The alt+tab applications switcher seems to randomly popup out of nowhere, perhaps from some interaction with the trackpad. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem and for me it doesn't seem to have anything to do with activity on the touchpad as it happened when I definitely wasn't touching it. It only happens on laptops, though. I never saw it on a desktop PC, nor on a Raspi, nor on a virtual machine, no matter whether running on a laptop or on a desktop PC. It definitely happens with different laptops but somehow it doesn't seem to have ever happened to anyone I know who uses Ubuntu (I know quite a lot of people who do).

Comment: Any inclination as to what might be causing it? Super annoying bug

Comment: No, absolutely no indication (I suppose you meant "indication"). Not even the moon phase. But it's not about your laptop being a macbook because mine are not. I think you can't even reduce it to the touchpad as there are many other differences between desktop PCs and laptops: WIFI is built in, Bluetooth, has a battery, has a webcam, has a built-in microphone, etc.

Comment: All I figured out until now is that it happens very irregularly and that it definitely isn't the keyboard actually pressing Alt+Tab. I figured this out by switching to a different TTY while it happened and switching back shortly after so that it was still switching applications. There were now `^[ ` printed on the TTY which would've happened if it was entered by the keyboard.